# Google Map API Drag event..?

Tags: google-maps, javascript, google-maps-api, google

The below code is working perfectly on click event to retrieve Lat/Long and Current Zoom level. How do I get the same when I hover mouse/drag on map Window (not on submit button)?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
var map;
function initialize()
{
var mapOpt = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:6,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);
}
function copyText()
{
document.getElementById("latlng").value=map.getCenter();
document.getElementById("Zoom").value=map.getZoom();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag',copyText);




</script>
</head>
<body>


<input type= "text" ID=latlng>
<input type="text" ID=Zoom><br>
<button onclick="copyText()">Submit</button>

<div id="googleMap"style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>


</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this example [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.html) might be helpful for you.

It has the function to dynamically displays Lat/Long information when mouse moves which similar to what you are looking for.

thanks,

Jinnan